# What natural numbers can be considered as the product of orders of elements of a finite (abelian) group

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Problem A5 from putname's competition 2009 asks to prove that there is no finite abelian group such that the product of order of its elements is equal to $2^{2009}$. Starting from this problem, for any group $G$ let $P(G)$ be the product of order of elements of $G$, i.e., $\prod_{x\in G}\mbox{O}(x)$. And consider the sets 
$$ A := \{ P(G) \; | \; G \mbox{ is a finite group } \} \mbox{ and } B := \{ P(G) \; | \; 
G \mbox{ is a finite abelian group } \}$$
(e.g., $2^{2009} \not \in B$ and clearly $3,5,7... \not \in A$ )

I have tried to describe $A,B$ in terms of their elements but it gets nowhere. So my goal is to find necessary or sufficient conditions for a nutural number to be an element of $A$ (or $B$). Even calculating $P(S_n)$ would be something! So any suggestion or ideal would be helpful.

Comment: I do not really understand the harsh reception of this question. But possibly it is only the way it is presented (phrasing it in the imperative like often done for excercises, and without motivation).

Comment: Have you tried computing the first few $n$, looking for patterns, consulting the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences? (Have you tried *anything*?)

Comment: But start with the smallest groups, those will give you the smallest values of $n$. Honestly, try *something*.

Comment: Don't start with $S_n$.  Try for every cyclic group, then every product of two cyclic groups -- first the product as Abelian group, and then not making the factors commute.

Comment: I guess this must mean "product of elements of all elements of $G$" rather than "product of orders of some elements of $G$", but the wording itself is completely unclear.

Comment: What's the motivation?

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe that the numbers which are representable as the product of the orders of all elements of a group can be characterized in some other "meaningful" way? -- If not, I think your question should rather be reformulated, e.g. to ask for properties of the set of these numbers, for necessary / sufficient conditions for a number to be in this set, or for algorithms to decide whether a given number is a member.

Comment: @StefanKohl I have no clue that there is a closed form for describing them. So I do agree with you and I will restate the problem.

Comment: Just because it's HARD doesn't mean it's a good question! I am inclined to think it's not very natural. Outside of solving Putnam questions, would anyone care?

Comment: @ToddTrimble Maybe  I did not explain well enough my reasons about stating the problem here. Anyway I have restated the problem.

Comment: @ToddTrimble You are right but in general! Concerninng to this problem regardless if it is hard or easy or it is motivated from putnam, it is a nice problem that worth thinking. +1

Comment: @MaximK Fine, I won't argue this further (I neither downvoted nor voted to close). *Chacun a son gout...*

Comment: There is some discussion of the original Putnam question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413546/subgroup-of-elements-of-order-at-most-2m

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the Putnam exam problem is about 2-groups and I highly doubt that the generalization proposed above is in any way tractable. That having been said, for $S_n$, every permutation has a cycle type labeled by a partition $\lambda=(\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2\geq\cdots\geq\lambda_n\geq0)$ of $n$. So

$$P(S_n)=\prod_{\lambda}\mathrm{lcm}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)^{|K_\lambda|}$$

where, $K_\lambda$ is the conjugacy class labelled by $\lambda$. Its order is $\frac{n!}{z_\lambda}$ where, for $\lambda=(1^{m_1},2^{m_2},\ldots)$, $z_\lambda=\prod_{i\geq 1} i^{m_i}(m_i!)$.

Comment: Shouldn't the $|K_\lambda|$ should be an exponent or did I just think through this answer too quickly?

Comment: This is only the product of element orders. I think a closed form was expected.

Comment: ARupinski: Right, $|K_\lambda|$ should be in the exponent. Silva: How much more explicit an answer do you think is possible in the $S_n$ case?